# How can I integrate useFont hook into my own theme.js file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm currently making an iOS app with Expo React Native and I want to call fonts in my own theme.js file. Unfortunately, I've tried many many ways but no one worked.

Helps will much appreciated.

My useFont section

```
const [ fontsLoaded ] = useFonts({
    'thin': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Thin.ttf'),
    'light': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
    'extraLight': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf'),
    'regular': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    'medium': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
    'semiBold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'bold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
    'extraBold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    'black': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Black.ttf'),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) { return null; }
```

and my theme.js

```
const colors = {
    primary: '#00FF66',
    background: '#181818',
    backgroundSecond: '#424242',
    black: '#000000',
    yellow: '#FFF500',
    white: '#FFFFFF',
    whiteSecond: '#F3F3F3',
    transparent: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
};

const sizes = {
    xxsmall: 8,
    xsmall: 10,
    small: 11,
    xxmedium: 12,
    xmedium: 14,
    medium: 16,
    large: 20,
    xlarge: 22,
    xxlarge: 24,
};

const bluramounts = {
    nav: 30,
    header: 50,
};

const safeArea = {
    left: 15,
    right: 15,
    contentSpace: 50,
    viewHeadingTop: 70,
    viewHeadingBottom: 25,
    headingBottom: 15,
};

export const theme = {
    colors,
    sizes,
    bluramounts,
    safeArea,
};
```

Tried calling them in one function then returning in theme.js but not worked.